# Visual Studio ViewportRelative Adornment layer not aligned to top

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm adding a control to the adornment layer in Visual Studio 2015 RC

```
[Export(typeof(AdornmentLayerDefinition))]
[Name(Constants.LAUNCH_ADORNMENT_LAYER)]
[Order(After = PredefinedAdornmentLayers.Caret)]
public static AdornmentLayerDefinition LaunchAdornmentLayer = null;

// ...

_layer = textView.GetAdornmentLayer(Constants.LAUNCH_ADORNMENT_LAYER);
_layer.AddAdornment(AdornmentPositioningBehavior.ViewportRelative, null, null, _launchControl, null);
```

It works fine on one of my machines, but on another one, **the control is located in an arbitrary location on the screen, usually so low that parts of the control are clipped by the bottom of the screen**. Scrolling the document up and down does not affect the positioning of the adornment.

Using Live Visual Tree, I found that the Adornment Layer is not aligned to the top (red rectangle outlines where `_launchControl` is located as it's hidden by VS)

[image: screenshot]

I tried forcing the elements towards the top, unsuccessfully. It makes the adornment layer's positioning relative to the position of the scroller (so it disappears off the screen when I scroll)

```
Canvas.SetTop(_launchControl, 0d);
Canvas.SetTop(_layer as System.Windows.UIElement, 0d);
```

Am I using `AddAdornment` wrong? **How do I fix the position of the adornment layer to the top of the viewport**?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get proper alignment, the **top** must be set to include the `ViewportTop` property of the text view:

```
_layer.AddAdornment(AdornmentPositioningBehavior.ViewportRelative, null, null, _launchControl, null);
Canvas.SetTop(_launchControl, _textView.ViewportTop);
```